# Fluentd Not parsing the last line of the log

Tags: java, logging, fluentd

I am currently setting up efk stack to parse my java logs (log4j) . I am able to parse all the logs except the last line of the log. so for eg.

```
2019-05-17 07:19:35,708 WARN log-line-1

2019-05-17 07:19:35,708 WARN log-line-2
```

so `log-line-1` is parsed, but not `log-line-2`. Otherwise I am able to parse everything.

I have tested my regex (https://rubular.com/) and it works fine.

Following is the configuration for fluentd:

```
format multiline

format_firstline /\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2},\d{3}/

format1 /(?<logtime>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2},\d{3})[\s](?<LEVEL>[A-Z]+)(?<message>(?=([\w\W\s]*?\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[\s]*\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\,\d{3}))([\w\W\s]*?)(?=(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[\s]*\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\,\d{3}))|((.|\s)*))/

@type tail

time_key logtime
```

Comment: @Laurenz Albe:- Thanks for editing the question !!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and
I dont know if this can help you but it's worked fot me.

td-agent.conf:

```
    ...
    @type tail
    format multiline
    format_firstline  /^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2},\d{3} (?<type>[A-Z]+) (?<message>.*\n.*)/
    format1 /^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2},\d{3} (?<type>[A-Z]+) (?<message>.*\n.*)/
    ...
```

I think that `(?<message>.*\n.*)` could help because it's include multiple `/n`,include 
 all the lines after.

try it [here](https://regex101.com/).

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.fluentd.org/v/0.12/input/tail

Look up the **multiline_flush_interval** parameter.  Same thing happened to me until I set this parameter to 0s.  After processing the rows above the last, it then processes the last row within a second.